# how to import a package that is written in c or shell and use in python

Tags: c, python-3.x, wrapper

I'm working on a project which a third party has already developed code for in C, but I need to be writing in python. is there a way to import/install it by wrapping it? or in a simpler way?

Comment: Use `ctypes` builtin module

Answer (score -1):

Maybe You should Check Out Cython.

[Cython.org - C Extensions for Python](http://cython.org)

Comment: ok so I installed cython in the terminal but when I write "cimport plt_rrs" it still says that its not defined

Comment: Have You Added Python to the system path.?